# AngularJS nested ng-repeat with grouped lists does not loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

My object model is a list of ItemLines, which each contain a number("quantity") of "part". Here is the data structure:

> `ordersItemLines = [{
>           "quantity": 1,
>               "part": {
>               "id": "part1",
>                   "name": "Part One",
>                   "quantity": null,
>                   "part_action": {
>                   "id": "Action1"
>               }
>           }, ...]`

I am trying to display a list of parts, grouped by Part.Action, and then grouped by Part.id, to finally display the number of parts with the same ID found for a given action.

But somehow, the nested ng-repeat keeps iterating on the first value of `grouping['itemLines']` from the parent ng-repeat. See the screenshot here:
[image]

And finally here is the code in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jubri/haxqH/).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Removing underscores' _memoize() function on the groupById filter fixes the issue, but reinstates the error: `Uncaught Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!`. See the new [JSFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/jubri/JLuvh/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this look like what you wanted?   http://jsfiddle.net/zz3m5/4/

I just cleaned up your fiddle, used `_.groupBy` and Angular's `(key, value) in object` comprehension to come up with this.  Hope this is what you required.
[image]